# Regular expressions: Getting everything except certain matching strings

Tags: c#, regex

Good day,

I am quite new to regular expressions so please bear with me.

In my system I use 4 filters in a grid.
In three of them it is a simple match to some subtext using the built-in functionality
e.g.

1. Filter 1: show everything containing "F0".
2. Filter 2: show everything containing "P0".
3. Filter 3: show everything containing "D0".

These filters work fine.

My problem is that I need to show everything else in filter 4 (named 'Other'). And it might be anything.

I can override the builtin filtering with a Regular Expression and I was thinking of using one to find everything that does NOT contain the three pieces of text ("F0", "P0", "D0").
This text will always be the 4th and 5th letter of the word.

But how would such an expression look?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The best I could do was the following, where I tried negative look-ahead

```
^...(?!F0).*|^...(?!P0).*|^...(?!D0).*
```

But this always results in a true as these are ORs and I need to AND them.

Example data:

- EDMF01 - should not be selected
- EDMF02 - Should not be selected
- EDMF03 - Should not be selected
- EDMP01 - should not be selected
- EDMP02 - should not be selected
- EDMD01 - should not be selected
- EDMMIS - should be selected
- FXMMIS - should be selected
- JSEDTP - should be selected
- any word not containing "F0", "P0" or "D0" - should be selected

Comment: You are simply trying to do `^(?!.*[DFP]0).*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a single

```
^...(?![FPD]0).*
```

or even

```
^.{3}(?![FPD]0)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E...%28%3F!%5BFPD%5D0%29.*&i=EDMF01%20-%20should%20not%20be%20selected%0D%0AEDMF02%20-%20Should%20not%20be%20selected%0D%0AEDMF03%20-%20Should%20not%20be%20selected%0D%0AEDMP01%20-%20should%20not%20be%20selected%0D%0AEDMP02%20-%20should%20not%20be%20selected%0D%0AEDMD01%20-%20should%20not%20be%20selected%0D%0AEDMMIS%20-%20should%20be%20selected%0D%0AFXMMIS%20-%20should%20be%20selected%0D%0AJSEDTP%20-%20should%20be%20selected&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of input
- `...` / `.{3}` - any 3 chars other than a newline
- `(?![FPD]0)` - no `F` or `P` or `D` followed with `0` immediately to the right of the current location is allowed
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as many as possible (if you are using the pattern within `Regex.IsMatch` the `.*` is not necessary as the method allows partial string matching).